# Conditional value entered in specific cell in a range, unlocks another specific cell in another range (VBA, Range Offset)

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

I am VERY new to VBA, but trying my best to catch on, reading everything I can, and testing as much as I can. I simply cannot figure this out after days of trying and I am begging for help, please!

What I specifically need:
If a value of 9 (and only 9) is entered into cell U13, then cell AZ13 is unlocked (no other value entered will unlock AZ13). OR if a value of 9 is entered into cell U14, then cell AZ14 is unlocked, and so on down the sheet to approximately U300/AZ300.

I have successfully achieved the desired result on the first line U13/AZ13 with the code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
    If Range("U13").Value <> 9 Then
        Range("AZ13").Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("U13").Value = 9 Then
        Range("AZ13").Locked = False
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
End Sub
```

The part I can't for the life of me get to work is moving to the next line.  I have tried several variations of the above code and about 100 other codes including:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
    If Range("U13:U200").Value <> 9 Then
        Range("U13:U200").Offset(0, 31).Select.Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("U13:U200").Value = 9 Then
        Range("U13:U200").Offset(0, 31).Select.Locked = False
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
End Sub
```

I have tried the above with ".select.locked" as well as just ".locked".
I am just learning about using range offset, but did try to modify to only move 1 cell over (0,1) just in case I counted the wrong number of cells, but that did not work either. This particular code gives me a run-time error (type mismatch); debug points to this line:

```
If Range("U13:U200").Value <> 9 Then
```

Any help in the right direction is GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!

Kay

Comment: You will need to loop the range, you will not be able to compare an array of values to a single value.

Comment: You get a type mismatch error because you can't compare an entire range to `9`. You need to loop over it.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do in the second example?

Comment: I just want to get the first example (which works for that particular line), to do the same for all additional lines in the sheet. I am currently looking up how to loop correctly based on the first two comments as that appears to be my problem.

Comment: Can any of you tell me - do I need to add the loop to the first example (the one that works for the one line), or is it something that is missing from the 2nd example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you need to loop.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
    For Each c In Me.Range("U13:U200").Cells
        c.Offset(0, 31).Locked = c.Value <> 9
    Next c
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
End Sub
```